# ng serve --ssl parameter - angular 17

Tags: angular-cli

I am upgrading an angular 16 application to angular 17 but i am having problems with ng serve.

I was using this ng serve command with angular 16 to run my application with https:

ng serve --port 4201 --ssl --ssl-cert my-cert.pem --ssl-key my-key.key

But after upgrade to angular 17 its returning this error:

Error: Unknown arguments: ssl, ssl-cert, ssl-key

It looks like this parameters were removed from ng serve and i didnt found any additional information on how to deal with it.

Someone knows how to run an angular 17 application with https?

Comment: can you upgrade the version of node.js to 18?

Comment: hi @NarenMurali, I am using node 18.16.1 and getting this error

Comment: these arguments still valid in angular 17. and seems work fine. https://angular.io/cli/serve. If you are not yet tried, delete node_module folder and reinistall dependencies to see. also it would be good to check if npm version match node version and clear npm cache